# check if the phone number exist in ms table

Tags: .net, vb.net

how i can know if the phone number exist in ms database or not ?

I'm using this code but i have error , i think i need to get all phone number as array and search in array if the number exist or not .

```
Dim number As String
    con.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "select cphone from cust "
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        number = dr(5)
    End While
    con.Close()

    If TextBox5.Text = number Then
        MsgBox("exist")
    Else
        MsgBox("NOT-exist")
    End If
```

but i think there is easy way to do this , any help please

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim ReturnValue as object
Dim sql As String = "select 1 from cust where cphone = @cphone"
using (Con as OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) 
    using (cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, Con))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@cphone).Value = TextBox5.Text
        Con.Open()
        ReturnValue = cmd.ExecureScalar()
        Con.Close()
        If ReturnValue Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("exist")
        Else
            MsgBox("NOT-exist")
        End If
    end using
end using
```

Explanations:

- [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) blocks provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.
- [Parametized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) ensure [sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) safety
- Using [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the first value that returns from a query. in this case, if the text in `TextBox5` doesn't match any cphone in the database, `Nothing` will return, this is why I've used the `ReturnValue` object

**Note**: Code written directly here, I might have made some syntax mistakes, but this is the general direction you should take your code to.

Comment: i have error in this : using (con as new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
    using (cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con))

Comment: I've written this code directly here as an example. Usually I do add a note about it, somehow I forgot to do it. Anyway, there was a missing `)` in the first using statement that I've fixed now.

Comment: See my edited answer. It's been a while since my VB.Net days, I'm mostly working in c# now, so I might have missed a thing or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do checking in Query

```
Dim sql As String = "select cphone from cust where cphone = " + TextBox5.Text
```

Instead of the number you can even return a `BIT` or `TOP 1`
You can use `ExecuteScalar` which would improve performance as well.

Comment: 2 comments in the price of one: **First**, use parameters instead of string concatenation. **Second**, replace `number` with `TextBox5.Text`.

Comment: Sure. Those are 2 great and valid points. Feel free to add a parameter version. I'm not sure how to do it in VB.